# How to make a react-Leaflet map jump to a different latlong via states or props?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

I'm only 2 weeks into React, and while I learned a lot, some of the React thinking still eludes me.

Right now, I have a React-leaflet map on the left half of the page. I have 3 markers on it, and when I click on each market, it setView properly, as the viewpoint shifts properly and all that. Got the zoom level figured out too, so it shifts nicely.

```
//TestMap.jsx
const MapLeaflet = () => {

const mapRef = useRef(null);
const [someLocations] = useState([
    [-55, 50],
    [-46, 30],
    [-64, 71]])

useEffect(() => {

    const w = 1000
    const h = 1000
    const url = "./custommap.jpg"

    var map = mapRef.current.leafletElement;

    var sw = map.unproject([0, h], 1);
    var ne = map.unproject([w, 0], 1);

    var bounds = [sw, ne]

    const image = L.imageOverlay(
      url,
      bounds
    ).addTo(map);

    map.fitBounds(image.getBounds());

  })

function centerMapView(e) {
    const { leafletElement } = mapRef.current;
    if (e) {
      console.log(e.latlng)
      leafletElement.setView(e.latlng, 4);
    }
  }

return (
    <LeafletMap
      ref={mapRef}
      crs={CRS.Simple}
    >
      {someLocations.map((position, i) => (
        <Marker
          position={position}
          key={i}
          onClick={centerMapView}
        >
        </Marker>
      ))}
    </LeafletMap>
  );
};

export default MapLeaflet;
```

This runs perfectly. Here's my App.js

```
class App extends Component {

render() {
    return (
      <Wrapper>
        <Row>
          <Col size='6'>
            <div style={{ backgroundColor: "#000" }}>
              <Testmap />
            </div>
          </Col>
          <Col size='6'>
             <p><a href="#loc1">LOCATION1</a></p>
             <p><a href="#loc2">LOCATION2</a></p>
             <p><a href="#loc3">LOCATION3</a></p>
          </Col>
       </Row>
    </Wrapper>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Here's the problem. I want some links on the RIGHT half of the webpage to do the same. Basically, the LOCATION1, LOCATION2, and LOCATION3. I want them to shift the map to center on the matching locations.

With regular leaflet.js, I'd just call setView(x,y) with onClick event handler. But how would I do this with React / React-leaflet?

I know I need to pass "CurPos" (which is one of the someLocations I had defined in TestMap)... Or maybe I can pass the index of someLocations, like someLocations[1]? And then what?

(You can assume all the tags are defined properly, as they are mostly just quasi-bootstrap wrappers)

Answer (score 1):

A couple of realizations:

a) You can't pass a state into a functional component, and TestMap is a functional component. I ended up rewriting that as a regular class component.

b) Then ran into a bunch of incompatibilities as I can't use *useEffect* and similar stuff. I ended up using createRef as it was already used.

c) Found myself bound to the wrong object and had to change the .bind of the *centerMapView" (didn't need to when it's a functional component).

d) had to add "this." to a bunch of other bits.

But the end result is something that works. The link's called handleClick(), which called centerMapView2() with something in somelocations array and moved it. This may not be 100% correct running code, but should be close enough for you to understand the code.

Updated source code:

```
class MapLeaflet extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.mapRef = createRef()

    // const [curPos, setcurPos] = useState(0)
    this.centerMapView = this.centerMapView.bind(this)
  }
componentDidMount() {
    var map = this.mapRef.current.leafletElement;
    console.log(this.mapRef)
    const w = 1000
    const h = 1000
    const url = "./custommap.jpg"
    L.Marker.prototype.options.icon = customMarker;
    var sw = map.unproject([0, h], 1);
    var ne = map.unproject([w, 0], 1);
    var bounds = [sw, ne]
    const image = L.imageOverlay(
      url,
      bounds
    ).addTo(map);
    map.fitBounds(image.getBounds());
  }

  centerMapView(e) {
    console.log(this)
    let { leafletElement } = this.mapRef.current;
    if (e) {
      leafletElement.setView(e.latlng, 4);
    }
  }

centerMapView2(id) {
    let { leafletElement } = this.mapRef.current;
    var curPos = someLocations[id]
    leafletElement.setView(curPos, 4);
  }

render() {
    return (
      <Map
        ref={this.mapRef}
        crs={CRS.Simple}
      >
        {someLocations.map((position, i) => (
          <Marker
            position={position}
            key={i}
            className={i}
            icon={customMarker}
            onClick={this.centerMapView}
          >
          </Marker>
        ))}
      </Map>
    );
  }
}
export default MapLeaflet;
```

Then app.js looked like this:

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.map2Element = React.createRef();
  }

  state = {}

  handleClick = id => {
    this.map2Element.current.centerMapView(id - 1)
  };

render() {
    return (
      <Wrapper>
        <Row>
          <Col size='6'>
            <div style={{ backgroundColor: "#000" }}>
              <Testmap />
            </div>
          </Col>
          <Col size='6'>
             <p><a href="#loc1" key=1 onclick={()=> this.handleClick(location1)}>LOCATION1</a></p>
             <p><a href="#loc2" key=2 onclick={()=> this.handleClick(location2)}>LOCATION2</a></p>
             <p><a href="#loc3" key=3 onclick={()=> this.handleClick(location3)}>LOCATION3</a></p>
          </Col>
       </Row>
    </Wrapper>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```